# What does it mean for two random variables to be independent?

Tags: probability, independence, uniform-distribution

Say I have a random variable X, **X~Uni(0,1)**. And for the parameters 0 < a < b < 1:

***Z = {a < x < 1} , Y = {0 < x < b}***

What does it mean for those two variables to be independent? I know that independence occures only when ***P(A and B) = P(A) * P(B)***, can this statement be shown here?

If I for example want to calculate ***P(Y|Z)***, and since ***P(Y) = 1/b***, and ***P(Z) = 1/1-a***, I get ***P(Y|Z) = P(Y and Z)/P(Z) = 1/b = P(Y).***

And also calculating ***P(Z|Y) = P(Z and Y)/P(Y) = 1/1-a = P(Z)***

What does these results mean? does it say anything about the independence of Z and Y? if not, how do I check the independence between those two?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your probabilities don't look quite right.

You should have P(Y)=P(0<X<b)=b and P(Z)=P(a<X<1)=1-a.

The probability of their intersection is then P(Y and Z)=P(a<X<b)=b-a. This is not equal to P(Y)*P(Z) in general (only in the special cas, so the events are not independent

Comment: But if the distribution function of a uniform distribusion is `1/b-a`, how did you get the P(Y) = b and P(Z) = a ? I mean,  I just took the max and min value given for P(0<X<b) :   `P(Y) = 1/b-a = 1/b - 0 = 1/b` and for  P(a<X<1) :`P(Z) = 1/b-a = 1/1-a` and moved forward from there..

Comment: The density function of X~Unif(a,b) is 1/(b-a). In your example you have X~Unif(0,1), so the density is just 1. To find P(Y)=P(0<X<b) you need to integrate this density between 0 and b. This is a rectangle with base b and height 1, so it has area 1.

Answer (score 0):

> What does it mean for two random variables to be independent?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Two_random_variables

-- in particular, see the part in terms of $f$ right at the end of that subsection

> "how do I check the independence"

Use that definition! Simply consider the joint density at say $(Y=0.6,Z=0.4)$ (i.e. not respecting the $Y<Z$ bound) compared to the product of the marginal densities at those values.

You don't need to explicitly evaluate any of them, just recognize that you can determine whether they're different immediately.